# How to choose which related contact gets the membership by relationship

Tags: civimember, relationships

We are on the latest CiviCRM 5.4.1 and Drupal 7.59. We have setup a membership type for a parent organisation (multi-site) to a child organisation. The relationship gets generated and membership gets associated by relationship which is great. What we are trying to figure out is how does CiviCRM let you choose which organisations receive the membership by relationship?

For example the parent organisation has 5 child organisations but has only paid for 3 related memberships. We can add the max related to 3 which is fine. How can we decide which 3 of the 5 child organisations will get the relationship. When it is organisation to individual membership the primary org membership has a create or delete option.

For parent organisation membership to child org membership it does not show.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The only way i know that you could do this would be to use a different relationship type

So base the inherited membership off eg "is child org member of"

So a child org that is not a member could have relationship of 'is child org of'

while the 3 that you are talking about could instead/also have 'is child org member of' relationship

if you were happy doing a customisation then you could change the inherited relationship feature and set it to only trigger if a custom field on the relationship is set to 'yes' for example

Comment: Thanks @petednz - We have setup the relationships for the site - however, we still don't get the edit option for members by relationship. It only picks up the individuals but not the organisations. Any ideas?

Comment: without knowing the detail of your set up i don't know what you mean by 'edit'. Inherited Relationships are a fixed concept - either some entity has the Relationship and hence inherits the membership, or they don't have the relationship and hence don't inherit the membership. it is not something you can pick and choose. hence you have to set up your Relationships so that anyone with the relationship needs to get the membership

Comment: Thanks @petednz. I will add a screenshot to this question which might help explain what is going on.

Comment: can this answer get a vote so StackExchange stop flagging that it doesn't have one :-)